# Getting value from a string in tcl

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, tcl

I have to get a patter from the specified string

This is first time I'm using tcl. Like in perl, I can simply get the grouped value with `$1` `$2` ... `$n`. In tcl I've tried this way ... actually this didn't even work...

```
while { [gets $LOG_FILE line] >= 0 } {
    if {[regexp -inline {Getting available devices: (/.+$)} $line]} {
        puts {group0}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `regexp`, you have two ways to get submatches out.

1. Without `-inline`, you have to supply variables sufficient to get the submatch you care about (with the first such variable being for the whole matched region, like `$&` in Perl):

   ```
   if {[regexp {Getting available devices: (/.+$)} $line a b]} {
       puts $b
   }
   ```

   It's pretty common to use `->` as an overall-match variable. It's totally non-special to Tcl, but it makes the script mnemonically easier to grok:

   ```
   if {[regexp {Getting available devices: (/.+$)} $line -> theDevices]} {
       puts $theDevices
   }
   ```
2. With `-inline`, `regexp` returns a list of things that were matched instead of assigning them to variables.

   ```
   set matched [regexp -inline {Getting available devices: (/.+$)} $line]
   if {[llength $matched]} {
       set group1 [lindex $matched 1]
       puts $group1
   }
   ```

   The `-inline` form works very well with multi-variable `foreach` and `lassign`, *especially in combination with `-all`*.

   ```
   foreach {-> theDevices} [regexp -inline -all {Getting available devices: (/.+$)} $line] {
       puts $theDevices
   }
   ```

Comment: The outer `while {[gets …] >= 0} {` is the same in all cases, so I've left it out for brevity.